# Create table partition in Hive for year,month and day

Tags: json, hive, hiveql, partitioning

I have my data folder in the below structure with 2 years data(2015-2017).

**AppData/ContryName/year/month/Day/app1.json**

For eg:

AppData/India/2016/07/01/geek.json

AppData/India/2016/07/02/geek.json

AppData/US/2016/07/01/geek.json

Now I have created an external table with partition.

```
PARTITIONED BY (Country String, Year String, Month String, day String)
```

After this, I need to add the partition in alter table statement.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD PARTITION (country='India', year='2016',month='01', day='01') 
location 'AppData/India/2016/07/01/'
```

Create add partition script to each and every day is not possible,

Is there any simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: Please elaborate regarding "is not possible"

Answer (score 2):

`msck repair table mytable`, but not with your current directory naming convention

#### Demo

**bash**

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /AppData/country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=01 
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /AppData/country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=02
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /AppData/country=US/year=2016/month=07/day=01
```

**hive**

```
create table mytable (i int) 
partitioned by (country string, year string, month string, day string)
location '/AppData'
;
```

---

```
hive> msck repair table mytable;
OK
Partitions not in metastore:    mytable:country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=01 mytable:country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=02 mytable:country=US/year=2016/month=07/day=01
Repair: Added partition to metastore mytable:country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=01
Repair: Added partition to metastore mytable:country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=02
Repair: Added partition to metastore mytable:country=US/year=2016/month=07/day=01
```

---

```
hive> show partitions mytable;
OK
partition
country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=01
country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=02
country=US/year=2016/month=07/day=01
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped, but the thing is I have the data for each and every day from 2015 to 2017. 

I can't able to create folders like,

hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /AppData/country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=01 

hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /AppData/country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=02

...........................................

hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /AppData/country=India/year=2016/month=07/day=30 

hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /AppData/country=India/year=2016/month=08/day=01
...........................................



Any automate way to create these subfolders?

Comment: How about renaming the folders with a bash script or adding the partitions using a bash script?

Comment: Side by side im moving this data to S3, so its not possible to execute shell scripts there :(, that is the problem here.

Comment: (1) According to google it seems possible (2) You don't have to execute the script on S3 but on your current data  and generate a batch of `alter table ... add partition ...` commands

Comment: is it possible to query these partitions as a singular date? or do all queries need to be like where day = 2 and month = 3 and year = 2016